# Select count Columns group by No

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Emp_No        Emp_Shift       Emp_Date    
500            AL              1/5/2015
600            S               2/5/2015
600            H               3/5/2015
500            S               4/5/2015
500            AL              5/5/2015
600            AL              6/5/2015
```

I need help on this issue , HOW TO RETURN count in 3 Columns >> 
EX:

```
Emp_No    Count Al    Count S    Count H
500         2            1           0
600         1            1           1
```

Comment: google SQL SERVER PIVOT

Comment: Or there's always the case when method:  `count (case when emp_shift = 'AL' then 1 else null end) as ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work. you have to provide separate case statement to each condition
SQLFIDDLE for the same [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21029/2)

```
    SELECT EMP_NO, 
           sum(CASE WHEN Emp_Shift = 'AL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_AL,
           sum(CASE  WHEN Emp_Shift = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_S,
           sum(CASE  WHEN Emp_Shift = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_H
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY EMP_NO;
```

Comment: Sorrry :( it return same Value like this 


556 Ismail Abdallah Ahmad Abu Awad 583 583 583
//
348 Antoun Basil Zuroub 2727 2727 2727

Comment: @IbrahimMAl-Mahareeq check the edited answer... replace sum instead of count

Comment: Sum yessss it work..many many thanks to you @ameya-deshpande 
u r my Hero :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT EMP_NO, COUNT(CASE
                     WHEN Emp_Shift = 'AL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COUNT_AL
                     WHEN Emp_Shift = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COUNT_S
                     WHEN Emp_Shift = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COUNT_H)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY EMP_NO;
```

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: I believe you need to use `sum` instead `count`. It will count regardless whether its 1 or 0. Not sure? try running this `Select COUNT (case when 1=1 then 0 else 1 end)`

Comment: You can use either `sum 1 else 0` or `count 1 else null`, those will give the same result.  Also, you can't derive 3 columns in one statement like you're trying, you have to have 3 separate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot :

```
declare @YOUR_TABLE TABLE 
    ([Emp_No] int, [Emp_Shift] varchar(2), [Emp_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO @YOUR_TABLE
    ([Emp_No], [Emp_Shift], [Emp_Date])
VALUES
    (500, 'AL', '2015-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'S', '2015-02-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'H', '2015-03-05 00:00:00'),
    (500, 'S', '2015-04-05 00:00:00'),
    (500, 'AL', '2015-05-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'AL', '2015-06-05 00:00:00')
;
select Emp_No,[AL] AS [Count Al],[S] As [Count S],[H] AS [Count H] from (
select Emp_No,[Emp_Shift],[Emp_Date] from @YOUR_TABLE)T
PIVOT(COUNT(Emp_Date) FOR Emp_Shift IN ([AL],[S],[H]))P
```

Using Pivot in Dynamic QUery :

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null
    drop table #t

CREATE  TABLE #t
    ([Emp_No] int, [Emp_Shift] varchar(2), [Emp_Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #t
    ([Emp_No], [Emp_Shift], [Emp_Date])
VALUES
    (500, 'AL', '2015-01-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'S', '2015-02-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'H', '2015-03-05 00:00:00'),
    (500, 'S', '2015-04-05 00:00:00'),
    (500, 'AL', '2015-05-05 00:00:00'),
    (600, 'AL', '2015-06-05 00:00:00')
;

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)
,@columns NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + N'[' + tbl.Emp_Shift + ']'
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT [Emp_Shift]
   FROM #t
   ) AS tbl

SELECT @statement = ' select Emp_No,[AL] AS [Count Al],[S] As [Count S],[H] AS [Count H] from (
select Emp_No,[Emp_Shift],[Emp_Date] from #t)T
PIVOT(COUNT(Emp_Date) FOR Emp_Shift IN  (' + @columns + ')) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @statement
```